# Assign dynamic variable in $.each loop and display separately in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have $each loop in jquery as below

```
some code---------
var temp="";
var msg_html="";

$.each(_d, function(index, val) {

        var currentID=val.id;

        if(temp.match(new RegExp("(?:^|,)"+currentID+"(?:,|$)"))) {

        msg_html+'_'+currentID        += messageTemplate(val.photo, val.from_name, val.message);

        } else{

        msg_html+'_'+currentID        += messageTemplate(val.photo, val.from_name, val.message);

        temp += currentID + ",";
        }

        });


some code ------------------
```

If the above code works, I can display as like,

```
        $('#someID_0').html(msg_html_0);
        $('#someID_1').html(msg_html_1);
        $('#someID_2').html(msg_html_2);
        ----
        ---
        ---
```

The problem in this code is that some error in  "msg_html+'_'+currentID  "as invalid assignment. Any other way to assign dynamically?

Comment: Any reason you can't do `$('#someID_' + currentId).html(/** html here **/)` inside the loop instead?

Comment: Try msg_html = msg_html + "_" + currentID + messageTemplate(val.photo, val.from_name, val.message);

Comment: the result in $.each should be combined by "+="

Comment: hi Dineshkani, by how to display $('#someID_' + currentId).html(msg_html_0).

Comment: Couldn't you use `$('#someID_' + currentId).append(messageTemplate(val.photo, val.from_name, val.message))` inside the `.each()` loop?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to assign different variables, why not use an associative array instead with the keys of array being the IDs?

Hence your code would be:

```
some code---------
var temp="";
var msg_html={};

$.each(_d, function(index, val) {

        var currentID=val.id;

        if(temp.match(new RegExp("(?:^|,)"+currentID+"(?:,|$)"))) {

        msg_html[currentID]        += messageTemplate(val.photo, val.from_name, val.message);

        } else{

        msg_html[currentID]        += messageTemplate(val.photo, val.from_name, val.message);

        temp += currentID + ",";
        }

        });


some code ------------------
```

You can then display your html by using:

```
$.each(msg_html,function(index,val){
     $('#someID_'+index).html(val);
            ----
            ---
            ---
});
```

Comment: but for var msg_html=array();  ReferenceError: array is not defined

Comment: Fixed the answer to implement your corrections. If the answer fits your needs, please check the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval`.

E.g.,

```
$.each(_d, function(index, val) {

    var currentID=val.id;

    if(temp.match(new RegExp("(?:^|,)"+currentID+"(?:,|$)"))) {

        eval("msg_html"+'_'+currentID +" += " + messageTemplate(val.photo, val.from_name, val.message));

    } else{

        eval("msg_html"+'_'+currentID +" += " + messageTemplate(val.photo, val.from_name, val.message));

    temp += currentID + ",";
    }

});
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to define the variables before the loop, and assign them to empty strings? (Otherwise the variable names being evaled don't exist so trying to use += will give an error.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you want but you can try to use use [StartsWith](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector along with [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
$("[id^='someID_']").each(function(index) {
    $(this).html(msg_html + '_' + index);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2eZ9N/)

Answer (score 0):

Use a object

var temp = "";
var msg_html = {};

```
$.each(_d, function(index, val) {
    var currentID = val.id;
    msg_html['_' + currentID] = '';
    if (temp.match(new RegExp("(?:^|,)" + currentID + "(?:,|$)"))) {
        msg_html['_' + currentID] += messageTemplate(val.photo, val.from_name, val.message);
    } else {
        msg_html['_' + currentID] += messageTemplate(val.photo, val.from_name, val.message);
        temp += currentID + ",";
    }
});
```

Then

```
$('#someID_0').html(msg_html._0);
$('#someID_1').html(msg_html._1);
$('#someID_2').html(msg_html._2);
```

Comment: I need assignment "+=" not "="

Comment: @JomyJoseph why do you want `+=`

Comment: [There's no such thing as a json object.](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: i need total data , not last one